# Eevee does not render animation properly

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

Blender renderer shows the first frame and the rest of the frames are repetitions of the second frame while the frame number is moving. The redered animation is also not proper.

Comment: Without any screenshot or .blend file is nearly impossible to help you

Comment: Have you got the same problem with cycle? Did you bake the animations?